# I need multiple PDF files to download for each loop using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

*With the below code I am getting all the loop data in one pdf file. But my requirement is I need a separate pdf file for each loop. So for each loop, I need user data in a separate pdf file that has to be download. I am working on it but getting all data in a single pdf only. So any suggestions to this code are very helpful thank you*

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $html = "";
    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $key => $val) {
        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jain_college where id=".$val);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

        $status=$row['status'];
        $name=$row['name'];

        $html.='
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><strong>e-Receipt for Payment</strong></th>
               <th><strong>Date:'.$row['date'].'</strong></th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Receipt Number</td>
                <td>'. $row['number'].'</td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Year</td>
                <td>'.$row['sem'].'</td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Program Name</td>
                <td>'. $row['program'].'</td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Course Name</td>
                <td>'. $row['course'].'</td>

              </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>Application Number/Reg Number</td>
                <td>'. $row['USN'].'</td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Student Name</td>
                <td>'. $row['name'].'</td>

              </tr>

                  <tr>
                <td>Student Mobile Number</td>
                <td>'.$row['mobile'].'</td>

              </tr>';


        if($status=='1') {
            $html.= '<tr>
                    <td>Tuition Fees</td>
                    <td>'. $row['tuition'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                      <tr>
                    <td>A&A Fees</td>
                    <td>'.$row['A_Fees'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Total Amount:</td>
                    <td>'. $row['total'].'</td>

                  </tr>';
        }
        if($status=='2') {
            $html.='<tr>
                    <td>DD Number</td>
                    <td>'.$row['ddnumber'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Bank Name</td>
                    <td>'.$row['bank'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>DD Date</td>
                    <td>'. $row['cashdate'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Amount:</td>
                    <td>'.$row['amount'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Drawn in Favour of:</td>
                    <td>'. $row['favour'].'</td>

                </tr>';
            }

            if($status=='3') {
                $html.='<tr>
                        <td>UTR Number</td>
                        <td>'. $row['rtgs_number'].'</td>

                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Bank Name</td>
                        <td>'. $row['rtgs_bank'].'</td>

                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>NEFT/RTGS Date</td>
                        <td>'. $row['rtgs_date'].'</td>

                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Amount:</td>
                        <td>'. $row['rtgs_amount'].'</td>

                      </tr>';

            }
            if($status=='4') {
                $html.='<tr>
                        <td>Cheque Number</td>
                        <td>'.$row['cheque_number'].'</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bank Name</td>
                        <td>'.$row['cheque_bank'].'</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cheque Date</td>
                        <td>'.$row['cheque_date'].'</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Amount:</td>
                        <td>'. $row['cheque_amount'].'</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Drawn in Favour of:</td>
                        <td>'. $row['Cheque_favour'].'</td>

                     </tr>';
                }

                $html.='<tr>
                   <td>PAN Number:</td>
                        <td>'.$row['pan'].'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td>Remarks:</td>
                        <td>'.$row['remark'].'</td>
                  </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <span style="page-break-after: always;"></span>';
            }

            $dompdf= new Dompdf();
            $dompdf->loadHtml($html); 

            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); 
            $dompdf->render(); 

            $dompdf->stream($name);
        }
```

Comment: You can not react to one single request with multiple responses. If you want to use code like this to download X PDFs, then you will have to provide the user with X links or something like that, so that they can trigger each download individually.

Comment: It is only possible to download single file. You should create a Zip File and add all those files to a zip and then download those zip. You could use `ziparchive`

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by modifying your code a little bit. just move the pdf creation process inside the loop and give it a try.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach ($_POST['check'] as $key => $val) {
    $html = "";
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jain_college where id=".$val);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

    $status=$row['status'];
    $name=$row['name'];

    $html.='
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><strong>e-Receipt for Payment</strong></th>
           <th><strong>Date:'.$row['date'].'</strong></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Receipt Number</td>
            <td>'. $row['number'].'</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Year</td>
            <td>'.$row['sem'].'</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Program Name</td>
            <td>'. $row['program'].'</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Course Name</td>
            <td>'. $row['course'].'</td>

          </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Application Number/Reg Number</td>
            <td>'. $row['USN'].'</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Student Name</td>
            <td>'. $row['name'].'</td>

          </tr>

              <tr>
            <td>Student Mobile Number</td>
            <td>'.$row['mobile'].'</td>

          </tr>';


    if($status=='1') {
        $html.= '<tr>
                <td>Tuition Fees</td>
                <td>'. $row['tuition'].'</td>

              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>A&A Fees</td>
                <td>'.$row['A_Fees'].'</td>

              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Total Amount:</td>
                <td>'. $row['total'].'</td>

              </tr>';
    }
    if($status=='2') {
        $html.='<tr>
                <td>DD Number</td>
                <td>'.$row['ddnumber'].'</td>

              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Bank Name</td>
                <td>'.$row['bank'].'</td>

              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>DD Date</td>
                <td>'. $row['cashdate'].'</td>

              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Amount:</td>
                <td>'.$row['amount'].'</td>

              </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Drawn in Favour of:</td>
                <td>'. $row['favour'].'</td>

            </tr>';
        }

        if($status=='3') {
            $html.='<tr>
                    <td>UTR Number</td>
                    <td>'. $row['rtgs_number'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Bank Name</td>
                    <td>'. $row['rtgs_bank'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>NEFT/RTGS Date</td>
                    <td>'. $row['rtgs_date'].'</td>

                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Amount:</td>
                    <td>'. $row['rtgs_amount'].'</td>

                  </tr>';

        }
        if($status=='4') {
            $html.='<tr>
                    <td>Cheque Number</td>
                    <td>'.$row['cheque_number'].'</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bank Name</td>
                    <td>'.$row['cheque_bank'].'</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cheque Date</td>
                    <td>'.$row['cheque_date'].'</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Amount:</td>
                    <td>'. $row['cheque_amount'].'</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Drawn in Favour of:</td>
                    <td>'. $row['Cheque_favour'].'</td>

                 </tr>';
            }

            $html.='<tr>
               <td>PAN Number:</td>
                    <td>'.$row['pan'].'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>Remarks:</td>
                    <td>'.$row['remark'].'</td>
              </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <span style="page-break-after: always;"></span>';


            $dompdf= new Dompdf();
            $dompdf->loadHtml($html);   
            $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); 
            $dompdf->render();      
            $dompdf->stream($name);             
        }

    }
```